# pycord - object has no attribute 'children'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

I am trying to create a discord bot using pycord. I have a view class as follows:

```
class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, link):
        self.link = link

    @discord.ui.button(label='480p', style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray, emoji='')
    async def button_callback_480(self, button, interaction):
        button.disable = True
        await MyView.video_finder()

        await interaction.response.send_message('downloading the file. Check the server for file')
        await interaction.followup.send('follow up added to the queue')

    @discord.ui.button(label='720p', style=discord.ButtonStyle.danger, emoji='')
    async def button_callback_720(self, button, interaction):
        button.disable = True
        await interaction.response.send_message('downloading the file. Check the server for file')
        await interaction.followup.send('follow up added to the queue')
```

Using the class above I have created a slash command. The code for the slash command is as follows:

```
@bot.command(description="Choose the quality of video you want to download")
async def ytdl(ctx, link: str):

    view = MyView(link)
    await ctx.respond('Choose the quality of video you want to download', view = view)
```

If I pass link as an argument to the class I get the following error:
also I do not get the buttons rendered too.

```
Ignoring exception in command ytdl:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/siddhant/dev/rick/theHomieRick/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/commands/core.py", line 124, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(arg)
  File "/home/siddhant/dev/rick/theHomieRick/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/commands/core.py", line 980, in _invoke
    await self.callback(ctx, **kwargs)
  File "/home/siddhant/dev/rick/theHomieRick/rick/commands.py", line 42, in ytdl
    await ctx.respond('Choose the quality of video you want to download', view = view)
  File "/home/siddhant/dev/rick/theHomieRick/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/commands/context.py", line 282, in respond
    return await self.interaction.response.send_message(
  File "/home/siddhant/dev/rick/theHomieRick/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/interactions.py", line 789, in send_message
    payload["components"] = view.to_components()
  File "/home/siddhant/dev/rick/theHomieRick/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ui/view.py", line 215, in to_components
    children = sorted(self.children, key=key)
AttributeError: 'MyView' object has no attribute 'children'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/siddhant/dev/rick/theHomieRick/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/bot.py", line 1114, in invoke_application_command
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/siddhant/dev/rick/theHomieRick/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/commands/core.py", line 375, in invoke
    await injected(ctx)
  File "/home/siddhant/dev/rick/theHomieRick/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/commands/core.py", line 132, in wrapped
    raise ApplicationCommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'MyView' object has no attribute 'children'
```

If I do not pass the argument 'link' it works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by `super().__init__()` before `self.link = link`
The class from which the attributes were inherited were not initialized because the `__init__()` in the current class was overriding the `__init__()` of the `discord.ui.View` class